# How can you investigate a daily traffic drain?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, traffic

Running Amazon EC2 instance, t3.large tier. And observing interesting situation:

[image]

Every night (UTC+1 midnight) the same NetworkOut jump occurs. What are my options to investigate it?

The EC2 runs nginx and varnish only. Nginx access logs don't show anything like that. So it must be something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can possibly make a script which periodically calls any tool like this (http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) or similar others. Keep appending this output to a file with time info. Run this script as a daemon.

Next day you can see what is that "culprit" process.

This thread seems to have more such tools : [Network usage top/htop on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368002/network-usage-top-htop-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks, among the tried ntop, ntopng, iftop nethogs was the most informative!

Comment: Now I wonder, what the heck is this: http://f.cl.ly/items/0d2I2k460S3Q3I2U1m3n/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-18%20at%2020.39.41.png